# <ul> disappears when background color is added to page

Tags: html, css

I couldn't find any question that would quite answer my questions; to my understanding, at least. So, I apologize if it's already been answered.

I've got an unordered list which I am using as a navigation bar. I created a sprite to have separate "images" for the hover states. This all works very nicely and I have it positioned in the middle of the page like I want.

The problem comes when I add a background-color to the stylesheet. The navigation menu disappears for some reason I can't quite figure out; perhaps it could be because of the CSS stylesheet reset coding I use?

here's an example... this is the html...

```
<header class="centered">

      <ul id="navbar">
          <li class="home"><a href="#" title="home">home</a></li>
          <li class="gallery"><a href="#" title="gallery">gallery</a></li>
          <li class="contact"><a href="#" title="contact">contact</a></li>
      </ul>

</header> <!-- end of header -->
```

this is the css...

```
#navbar{
     display: block;
     width: 481px;
     height: 55.5px;
     background: url(../images/navbar2.png) left top no-repeat;
}

#navbar li{
     display: block;
     float: left;
}

#navbar li a{
     display: block;
     height:55.5px;
     text-indent:-9999px;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.on{
     background-image: url(../images/navbar2.png);
}

#navbar li.home a{
     width:142px;
     background-position:-0px -55.5px;
}

#navbar li.gallery a{
     width:166px;
     background-position:-142px -55.5px;
}

#navbar li.contact a{
     width:173px;
     background-position:-308px -55.5px;
}
```

now, I'm applying the background color in this "CSS stylesheet reset" code at the beginning of my stylesheet... here's a snippet of it.

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background: transparent;
    background-color: #000000;    
}
```

Comment: why would you set the `background-color` in the reset code? it will apply to every element in the page. Add a new rule to apply it only to the `body`

Comment: Agreed with above comment. Also, are you putting your reset code below your own css? It sounds like that's what you're doing.

Comment: For further issues, you could start using an 'inspect element' tool that every browser has, that would had helped you with this issue. There you can activa/deactivate css properties so you know which one does what and when.

Comment: @koala_dev hit the nail on the head. I was using * {} instead of just body {} and was resetting my <li> background.